# Необходима ли постановка тире?

Tags: тире

Совсем рядом должна была быть остановка, а ещё чуть дальше (—) магазин.

Дни становились короче, а ночи (—) холодней.

Вой быстро перешёл на лай, затем (—) на короткое отрывистое тявканье.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Правило Розенталя:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

2. Тире ставится в неполных предложениях **при параллелизме конструкций** (предложений или частей предложения).

Остается догадаться, что это такое. Можно предположить, что речь идет о сходстве по структуре и интонации. **Но параллельная интонация должна быть параллельной** (как и экономика — экономной). Интересно, что все примеры на эту тему у Розенталя — это простые эллиптические предложения, где ничего параллельного как раз нет.

5. Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается **пауза**.

В общем, мало нам помог Розенталь, ничего конкретного. **Поэтому тире в неполных предложениях ставятся по интонации, с учетом пауз и ударений.** При решении возможны варианты.

(1) ***Совсем рЯдом /должна была быть остановка, а ещё чуть дАльше — магазин.***

Это параллельная структура. Все предложение делится на четыре части, а параллель составляют наречия (рядом, дальше). Именно эти наречия выделяются логическим ударением при чтении.

(2) ***Дни становились корОче, а ночи холоднЕй.***

Это предложение разделить на четыре  части сложно, поэтому параллельной интонации нет.

(3) ***Вой быстро перешёл на лАй, затЕм — на короткое отрывистое тЯвканье.***

Здесь параллельной структуры нет, но тире обозначает паузу. Дело в том, что наречие ***затем*** выделяется ударением, а следующая после наречия пауза обозначает пропуск слов *лай перешел*.

Сравнить: *Вой быстро перешёл на лАй, затем на тЯвканье.*  Здесь тире нет.

**И делаем вывод:** в первом варианте распространенность второй части предложения вынуждает нас разделить ее паузой и тире на две части.

**И еще такой вывод.** Часто решение о постановке тире и паузы можно считывать со структуры предложения, не задавая автору дополнительных вопросов.

Comment: "*Можно предположить, что речь идет о сходстве по структуре и интонации*" — однозначно. Но больше это относится к структуре. А интонация от элемента к элементу может идти по восходящей, например: *Сегодня будет просто салат, а завтра - торт с 30 коржами.*

Answer (score 5):

Розенталь разъясняет:

> 1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с
>      отсутствующим сказуемым):Влево, в углу, у дверей, на табурете — ведро
>      воды для жаждущих (Пом.); За калиткой — третий плац, строевой,
>      необыкновенной величины (Купр.); Мужики — за топоры… (А. Т.); И это вы
>      — при дочери? (Фед.); А в двери — бушлаты, шинели, тулупы… (М.); За
>      ночным окном — туман (Бл.); Олимпийский огонь — на нашей земле!
>      (Газ.); В роли обиженных — маленькие дети; И затем — минутная тишина;
>      Арбузов и дынь — горы; Коров — две; В ответ -— полное молчание;
>      Впереди — А. Карпов.
>
> При отсутствии паузы тире в эллиптическом предложении не ставится: А в
>   доме стук, ходьба… (Гр.); Вдруг передо мною рытвина глубокая (Л.);
>   Скрип шагов вдоль улиц белых, огоньки вдали (Фет); У Хохла пожар! (М.
>   Г.); Револьвер на стол! (К. Т.); Справа дверь в соседнюю комнату,
>   слева выход на террасу (так оформляются ремарки в пьесах); В этом вся
>   суть.

То же самое и о сложных предложениях:

> 5. Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое)
>      восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска
>      делается пауза: Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно
>      плохо (Т.); За окном вагона плыла кочковатая равнина, бежали
>      кустарники, дальние — медленно, ближние — вперегонку (А. Т.); Голоса
>      офицеров с каждой минутой становились громче, слова — резче, аргументы
>      — непримиримее (Гол.); Мир освещается солнцем, а человек — знанием
>      (Посл.); Подберите ещё несколько примеров, каких — не имеет значения;
>      У него в глазах — как бы поскорее отделаться от меня.

Так что зависит от автора: есть пауза - есть тире, нет паузы - нет тире. В первых двух примерах я бы поставила тире, в последнем нет, но это моё субъективное мнение, а как у автора - кто его знает..

Answer (score 3):

Есть правило, разрешающее в таких случаях иногда не ставить тире.

Розенталь:
**При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится:**
*Она прыгнула в лодку, я за ней...* (Лермонтов).
*Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку* (Чехов).
*Алёша смотрел на них, а они на него* (Чехов).
*Из нашей батареи только Солёный пойдёт на барже, мы же со строевой частью* (Чехов).
*У вора один грех, а у нас с хозяином десять* (Островский).
*Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие* (Леонов).
*Он был в свету, а я в темноте* (Толстой).

Тире ставится, если логическое ударение падает на слово до тире. Из-за этого образуется пауза.